# Advantages to Storing BINARY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, binary, blob, zlib

What are the advantages/disadvantages to storing small binary blobs directly in MySQL. I've read mixed opinions on the topic.. some say a lot of performance can be gained if large blocks of text are zipped and stored as binary or is it faster to use the filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have entities in the database, and corresponding files associated with those entities in the filesystem, there's nothing preventing them from getting out of sync (deleting an entity from the DB but not cleaning up the files, etc.  It also means backing up the database must happen at the same time as backing up the filesystem.

I used to feel that BLOBs in the database created fragmentation and can slow down reads when that data isn't needed, but you can get around that by putting the BLOB in a parallel table, so you only read it when it's needed.

Comment: Question: Don't plan to write my own FAT but if I were to compress large blocks of text from 200K down to 5k and store the bin data, then use zlib to expand it before the getter sends it back would there be any noticeable difference in performance? Or is it a waste of time?

Comment: If you can compress meaningful data by a factor of 40, that would be very impressive.  That aside, there are simply too many variables to say which would be faster (processor speed vs disk speed vs cache hit rate vs filesystem latency vs number of disk platters).  It would be worth testing.  If it's text though, keep in mind compressing it means you can't do indexing or full text search on it, if you'll ever need that.